# Forbid hiding Excel sheet

Tags: microsoft-excel

Is it possible to disallow a sheet in Excel from being hidden? I have a workbook with multiple sheets, many of which can and are hidden if not required. Some of the sheets should always be required, so I want to set the particular sheets to never be hidden.

Comment: Did you try this function `Private Sub Workbook_SheetBeforeDelete(ByVal Sh As Object)`  `End Sub`

Comment: Seems to have no effect

Answer (score 0):

Protect the workbook with "structure" ticked and set a password.

It is in the "Review" ribbon.

[image]